# How can I keep my pet dry if they wet the bed?

Tags: toilet-training, urination, disability

I have a geriatric bunny (11 years) who is having difficulties getting to in and out of the litter box, sometimes when he is not feeling well he will pee in his bed and it gets him all wet. [Urine Scald](http://www.disabledrabbits.com/urine-scald.html) can be a significant issue for disabled rabbits.  Wire bottom cages simply trade one negative scenario for another, so wire floors are not a viable option. As vegetarians rabbit poop from all but a very sick bunny consists of dry pellets so is not a significant concern if moisture in the environment is controlled.

I am looking for solution(s) for house rabbits, but solutions that are not species specific are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution came from Alyssa at Rabbit Wranglers.  It is extremely effective for rabbits; a microfiber/chenille bath mat.  These mats are effective at providing a soft barrier between the pet and any moisture.  An absorbent material is placed under the mat, with an moisture barrier as the lower most layer.  Alyssa uses an adult (humnan) incontinence pad.  Moisture is wicked away from the pet and absorbed by the towel or pad.  The texture of the mat is sufficient to support the weight of the average rabbit, keeping the bunny elevated above any moisture.  Rabbit dropping can be picked up from the mat throughout the day, they also shake off easily.

Everything is washed and changed once or twice a day.  The mats pictured below come in two brands, and several sizes, available at Marshals department store in our area.

[image: Packaging]
[image: In use]