# Bunny has tilted head

Tags: rabbits

I have a bunny that has a tilted head. I have been to the vet and he has an ear infection. He can't really move right now without help so if he pees before i get home he is laying in it. This had only happened twice but his fur is yellow and it smells awful. Any suggestions on how to tend to This problem?

Comment: Was your bunny having trouble moving when you took him to the vet, or has that developed recently?

Comment: He was having trouble when I took him.  He is starting to lift himself up again now.  He has been on antibiotics for about three weeks now.  He seems to be feeling better but his head is still tilted very badly. Which is causing to have trouble getting around.

Comment: Related [How do I care for a quadriplegic rabbit?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5466)

Comment: The answer to your specific question about wet bedding can be found at [How can I keep my pet dry if they wet the bed?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/4410) if you are considering a bath [read this](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1853)

Comment: The most common cause of head tilt in rabbits is [E Cuniculi](http://www.rabbit.org/journal/3-2/e-cuniculi.html) There is a test that can determine if your rabbit has been exposed to E Cuniculi I think it costs around $100.

Comment: It looks like we have existing answers for most (all?) of what you are asking here.  Is there anything we are missing?